# CSS Background property not working on server

Tags: html, css, background

I just uploaded my first site that I created to a server, but not everything is working. I have a couple of pictures which are inserted using the CSS "background : url() " property but for some reason the pictures aren't showing up. I've tried putting the pictures in different folders and changing paths. The pictures are currently in the main directory so this is how my code looks like:

```
body {
    /*background: linear-gradient(#2c3e50 75%, #ecf0f1 95%);*/
    /*background-color: #2c3e50 ; */
    /*background-color: #c0392b; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url("Elegant_background-3.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#main-container {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    width: 960px;
    height: 445px;
    background: url("towncar.png") top center no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
```

Any tips? The pictures were first in a 'pics' folder but I moved them and put them in the main directory
Here's the site: www.bayareasedans.com

Comment: There isn't any file named `Elegant_background-3.jpg` in the server's root.

Comment: or in the css folder. http://www.bayareasedans.com/css/Elegant_background-3.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the images will be source from the css relative to the css file (so presently they are being looked for at http://www.bayareasedans.com/css/Elegant_background-3.jpg, check the F12 developer tools), and secondly it appears you are on a Linux server, and case DOES matter, so Elegant_Background-3.jpg (notice with the captial 'B') worked fine for me under http://www.bayareasedans.com/Elegant_Background-3.jpg.

towncar.png works fine, no case issue assuming you get the path correct of http://www.bayareasedans.com/towncar.png as presently it is looking for it at http://www.bayareasedans.com/css/towncar.png

so changes required to the css are (assuming you do not move the image files form the root)

```
body {
/*background: linear-gradient(#2c3e50 75%, #ecf0f1 95%);*/
/*background-color: #2c3e50 ; */
/*background-color: #c0392b; */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url("/Elegant_Background-3.jpg"); /** Here **/
background-size: 100% 100%;
 }

#main-container {
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
width: 960px;
height: 445px;
background: url("/towncar.png") top center no-repeat; /** and Here **/
display: block;
}
```

Comment: ha! I tried changing the case on the E but not the B. :)

Comment: I once had a lot of pain not respecting case when I moved a site from a Windows server to a Linux server, I am now meticulous concerning case regardless of the server. Sometimes it helps to adopt a set naming convention, If you are going to use underscores and Capitals, then always use it, or always use lowercase - perferrably not a mixture of both; Anyway that helped me

Comment: 100% agree. all lower case for life for files on the server. not better, just consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs in CSS are relative to the location of the CSS file.

So for example if you're targetting a file in the root folder, from a css file in the css/ folder, then use:

```
url("../towncar.png")
```